# Google App engine Endpoint Version Migration V1 to V2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

We have created Google Endpoint api v1 using android studio.
We have received email from google cloud that is Google Api version v1 was deprecated. So we tried to update v1 to v2.
So referred following link for migrate. [https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android#before_you_begin](http://We%20have%20created%20Google%20Endpoint%20api%20v1%20using%20android%20studio.%20We%20have%20received%20email%20from%20google%20cloud%20that%20is%20Google%20Api%20version%20v1%20was%20deprecated.%20So%20we%20tried%20to%20update%20v1%20to%20v2.%20So%20referred%20following%20link%20for%20migrate.%20https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android#before_you_begin%20%20After%20change%20when%20we%20try%20to%20run%20that%20time%20show%20'.../backend/build/exploded-app'%20does%20not%20exist%20%20If%20I%20look%20at%20the%20directory%20tree%20within%20my%20project%20%20I%20can%20see%20the%20exploded%20directory%20%20%22../build/exploded-backend%22%20based%20on%20the%20module%20name%20%22backend%22%20and%20%20'endpointsDiscoveryDocs'%20that%20contains%20Discovery%20docs.%20Not%20available%20'.../backend/build/exploded-app'%20,%20'.../backend/build/endpointsClientLibs'%20%20I%20need%20a%20help%20what%20happened%20here.)

After change when we try to run that time show '.../backend/build/exploded-app' does not exist

If I look at the directory tree within my project 
I can see the exploded directory  "../build/exploded-backend" based on the module name "backend" and 'endpointsDiscoveryDocs' that contains Discovery docs.

Not available '**.../backend/build/exploded-app**' and '**.../backend/build/endpointsClientLibs**'

When i tried to execute, Build was successful but shown on
Error running backend: Cannot start process, the working directory '...\MyAppliaiton\backend\build\exploded-app' does not exist

Following build.xml are used in my android project

MyApplication build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle

```
**apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// V2: Apply the new Endpoints Framework client plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // V2: Add the new Endpoints Framework plugin dependencies
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chainsys.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    //compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    // V2: Endpoints Framework v2 migration
    endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'

}**
```

Backend build.gradle

```
**buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'
        // V2: Add the new App Engine and Endpoints Frameworks plugin dependencies
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

// apply plugin: 'appengine'


// V2: Apply new App Engine and Endpoints Framework server plugins
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

dependencies {

    //appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.42'

    // V2: Endpoints Framework v2 migration
    compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.7'

    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'


  //  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.42'
   // compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.42'
   // compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

}

// V2: Define deployment configuration using the new App Engine plugin
// with the appengine closure
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration


    deploy {   // deploy configuration

        // The following is used for acceptance tests and
        // is not required for a migration.
        project = findProperty("appengine.deploy.project")
        version = findProperty("appengine.deploy.version")
        def promoteProp = findProperty("appengine.deploy.promote")
        if (promoteProp != null) {
            promote = new Boolean(promoteProp)
        }
    }


}**
```

Backend web.xml

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.sugumar.p.myapplication.backend.MyEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>**
```

I need a help what happened here.

Comment: Need you to provide logs of what commands you're running and the full output, please.

Comment: Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:backend:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:backend:classes UP-TO-DATE
:backend:endpointsDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
:backend:_zipDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
:backend:war UP-TO-DATE
:backend:explodeWar UP-TO-DATE
:backend:assemble UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL                                                                                                     
Error running backend: Cannot start process, the working directory '...\MyAppliaiton\backend\build\exploded-app' does not exist

Comment: Please put this in your question, not in the comments. Can you also include your gradle (presumably) config? Or Maven if that's what you're using.

Comment: Updated saiyr. Please help me what my mistake

Answer (score 6):

I was updating my appengine module from Java 7 to Java 8 and Endpoints v1 to Endpoints v2 and it really is a pain in the ass.

I have solved it going to

> [backend-module]/[backend-module].iml

and changing the line

> value="C:\workspace\ [project] \ [backend-module] \build\exploded-app

to

> value="C:\workspace\ [project] \ [backend-module] \build\exploded-[backend-module]